# Does Stephen Hawking believe that General Relativity is wrong?

Tags: black-holes

Stephen Hawking recently said that black holes do not exist. According to Wikipedia, black holes are predicted by General Relativity. So it would seem to follow that Stephen Hawking believes that General Relativity is wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When I see a question like this my first instinct is to ask *"Did you read the paper? Or even the abstract?"*

Comment: Yes, I read the paper, but I'm not an expert on physics.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein I think you did not read the academic paper published by Hawking. A careful examination will show you that he never asserts that black holes don't exist.

Comment: He said, "The absence of event horizons mean that there are no black holes." He also says, "A different resolution of the paradox is proposed, namely that gravitational collapse produces apparent horizons but no event horizons behind which information is lost." These two statements together imply that he believes that black holes don't exist.

Comment: The continuation of the first quote is, *in the sense of regimes from which light can't escape to infinity*. That is, there are no *event horizons* (what your 2nd quote says) which is **different** from the black hole itself.

Comment: The 2nd sentence after your selective first quote also says, *This suggests that black holes should be redefined as metastable bound states of the gravitational field*. Is that unambiguous enough an assertion that he believes BHs do exist?

Comment: But you can't have a black hole without an event horizon in the sense of regimes from which light can't escape to infinity. Otherwise, the hole can't be black since light can escape. But I thought GR predicts black holes.

Comment: All the news outlets are reporting that he said that black holes don't exist.

Comment: I think when he says, "This suggests that black holes should be redefined as metastable bound states of the gravitational field", he means that black holes don't exist, so you have to redefine the phenemonon that was once assumed to be explained by a black hole as something else.

Comment: Isn't the *point* of his paper to show that you *can't* have an event horizon due to the information problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, he does not think that GR is wrong. Actually, in his article [on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5761), he gives some ideas in order to (try to) solve a problem associated to the information paradox for evaporating black holes. That would mean that the usual idea of black hole we have would not longer be accurate. It does not imply that GR is wrong (at least on the domain of validity where we believe it provides a pretty good description of physics).

Comment: So then we have a contradiction. If he doesn't believe in BHs but believes in GR, this contradicts the conventional wisdom that GR implies BHs, as is stated in the Wikipedia article on BHs.

Comment: Someone should update the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Not really. Because what Hawking is talking about is actually on the wedge of validity of GR. It does involve quantum effects ; something that GR is not able to take into account. To be accurate, nobody believes in GR because we know there should be another theory to describe quantum gravity. But, as long as some assumptions are verified, GR is a theory that describe the physics of gravitation in a very convincing way. And if you have even more restricting assumptions, you don't need GR ; you can use Newtonian theory. It will gives you very good results, as long as used in a correct framework.