# Is it possible for things to fall past the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation

Everything I can find says that time dilation approaches infinity at the event horizon of a black hole. Black holes evaporate over a finite amount of time. Wouldn't this imply that somebody falling into a black hole would eventually just see the event horizon shrink away from them as fast as they fall into it. This seems to imply that its impossible for anything to fall past the event horizon, everything just gets very close to the event horizon and then the black hole evaporates from underneath them.

Ive read through as many posts as I could find addressing this. The most direct one being this one:
https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/fall_in.html

In all the posts that claim to have a definite answer I don't understand it. And all the posts I feel like I understand don't claim a definite answer.

Comment: Astrophysical black holes can accrete matter and grow in mass (this is an observational fact). For matter crossing the horizon nothing special happens (but once the horizon is crossed it can not be brought back). However, when you, from the distance, observe that accretion matter, you see it redshifted and getting closer and closer to the horizon (at a certain point it is so redshifted that it's too dim to be seen). Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79054/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202935/226902, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104346/226902

Comment: Duplicate of: [Can matter really fall through an event horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/can-matter-really-fall-through-an-event-horizon). See ProfRob's excellent answer for the calculation - even if you can't follow the meaning, note $\Delta t \lt \text{finite}$

Comment: The first paragraph of the Baez article says: _"I have to hit the singularity eventually, and before I get there there will be enormous tidal forces—forces due to the curvature of spacetime—which will squash me and my spaceship in some directions and stretch them in another until I look like a piece of spaghetti."_

Comment: If we could measure one way speed of light, we could know what part of the trip a light pulse spends an eternity, when the light travels to event horizon and back up. So we must be unable to see if the hole shrinks or not, when falling into a black hole,  because that would tell us about one way speed of light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light    I disagree about closing the question.