# Information Preservation and Weather Forecasting for Black Holes

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, black-hole-firewall

Referencing Stephen Hawking's recent paper [*Information Preservation and Weather Forecasting for Black Holes*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5761) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95366/why-does-stephen-hawking-say-black-holes-dont-exist) question. I understand concept of *holding* the information on the apparent horizon of a black hole for later release in the form of garbled radiation, but how is it that this differs ( if at all ) from the Hawking Radiation generated by the Unruh effect near the horizon?

My, possibly flawed, train of thought is that the aforementioned black hole sucks in everything in matter in it's immediate surroundings, and due to the Feynman diagram that corresponds to particle-antiparticle pairs spontaneously popping into existence with one particle on the other side of the horizon, the energy from the matter sucked in, is imparted to which ever particle is outside of the event horizon to repay the energy debt to the Universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Neil deGrasse's explanation of the Hawking effect, the radiation that leaves the black hole via this effect is indeed that of the matter that previously fell in.