# Black Holes can't exist?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

So in this article [here](http://unc.edu/spotlight/rethinking-the-origins-of-the-universe/), Mersini-Houghton says that Black Holes can't exist. Is there any truth to this?

references:

http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1406.1525

http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1409.1837

Comment: No, it is flawed just like every other attempt in the past. Read Unruh's official response here: http://www.iflscience.com/physics/physicist-claims-have-proven-mathematically-black-holes-do-not-exist

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95366/

Comment: I haven't read the actual paper, but just the abstract seems to suggest that the article is discussing the behavior of stellar collapse.  Even if black holes aren't formed by that method, it would not be equivalent to the statement that "black holes can't exist".  Other formation pathways may be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea that black holes can't exist goes against the mainstream viewpoint, and also goes against observational evidence.  See the [Observational evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Observational_evidence) section of Wikipedia's [Black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) article.

There would need to be independent corroborative papers published in [peer-reviewed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review) journals for this to hold up.  Mersini-Houghton's earlier paper in [Physics Letters B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_Letters) counts, but [arXiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv) isn't peer-reviewed, so her more recent paper that was only "published" in arXiv doesn't count for much.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy the "only 'published' in arXiv  [so it] doesn't count for much" argument. There are papers on arXiv that weren't published that are worth something. As it stands, I do not really see how this is anything more than a link-only answer.

Comment: It wasn't anything more than a link-only question.

Comment: In all seriousness papers on arXiv that attract any attention (as this one has done) are reviewed by the author's peers. There is not the formal step in a which an editor then gives it a up/down check, but this will receive plenty of attention sussing out any errors that might exist.