# How do black holes get their magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, quasars

I imagine the magnetic field comes from the accretion disk. But what causes it to "spring" upward?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226458/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39161/2451

Comment: What do you mean by spring upward?

Comment: What does "spring upward" refer to?

Comment: *I imagine the magnetic field comes from the accretion disk.* A [Kerr-Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr–Newman_metric) black hole without an accretion disk has a magnetic field, but such a hole isn’t astrophysically relevant as far as we know.